# get group members from azure ad via microsoft graph

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I am working in asp.net application Authenticate with external identity provider (Azure Active Directory)

I want to get group members from azure ad via microsoft graph

How can I do that ??

Comment: Can you please tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck? This will also help us answer your question better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems You are trying to get all group members from a specific group. Just [Get the group Id that is `Object Id`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) on azure portal. See the below screen shot.

[image]

***Code Snippet :***

You could try following code snippet which work fine as expected.

```
    //Token Request End Point
    string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token";
    var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

    //I am Using client_credentials as It is mostly recommended
    tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
        ["client_id"] = "b6695c7be_YourClient_Id_e6921e61f659",
        ["client_secret"] = "Vxf1SluKbgu4PF0Nf_Your_Secret_Yp8ns4sc=",
        ["resource"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/" 
    });

    dynamic json;
    AccessTokenClass results = new AccessTokenClass();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

    json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);


    //New Block For Accessing Group Member List from Microsoft Graph Rest API
    var groupId = "Group Id which Member You want to Retrieve";
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{0}/members"),groupId);
    //Passing Token For this Request
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", results.access_token);
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    //Get User List With Business Phones and Mobile Phones
    dynamic objGpraphUserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

***Class Used:***

```
 public class AccessTokenClass
    {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string resource { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
    }
```

***Permission:***

You need to set [`User.Read.All, Group.Read.All, Directory.Read.All`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions) `Application permission` on  Microsoft Graph API on azure portal.

[image]

***Test Request Result:***

[image]

For more details you could refer to [Official Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#permissions)

Hope it would help. Feel free to share if you encounter any problem.

Comment: what is a ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials" ??

Comment: Its a [Microsoft Authentication Protocol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow#get-a-token). You have to get token first for any `Microsoft Graph` operation and `client_credentials` protocol is one of the most recommended token protocol. Hope you got my points.

Comment: If you have token just skip token part and focus on `Microsoft Graph Request` part. If you have any more question feel free to share.

Comment: I get this 
{ "error": { "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken", "message": "CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217", "innerError": { "request-id": "7e8b8a5b-9c33-4162-bf02-68d8b8774555", "date": "2020-02-28T08:37:12" } } }

Comment: Which protocol you are using? Update you question with your  token request code

Comment: it's V2.0 protocol

Comment: Then replace `["scope"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"` instead of `["resource"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/"` You should update your question with what you have tired. Its very weird to ask for solution without showing code!