# How to create SAS token for Azure Data Lake Store (Gen-2) using service principals (clientId and clientSecret) in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, service-principal, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-sas

I have the clientId and clientSecret of Data Lake Store (Gen-2) and I am looking for a way to create SAS token for it in a programmatic way using C#. I have gone through the documentation but have not find a way to create a SAS token. Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks.

As suggested by Md Farid Uddin Kiron, I used this code but unsuccessful:

```
//Token Request End Point
string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token";
var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

//I am Using client_credentials as It is mostly recommended
tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
                ["client_id"] = "--------",
                ["client_secret"] = "-------",
                ["resource"] = "https://<datalake gen2 name>.dfs.core.windows.net/"
            });

            dynamic json;
AccessTokenClass results = new AccessTokenClass();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var tokenResponse = client.SendAsync(tokenRequest).GetAwaiter();

json = tokenResponse.GetResult().Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter();
results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);
```

It is giving me status 400 error.

Comment: Please have look on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436419/get-group-members-from-azure-ad-via-microsoft-graph/60437235#60437235)  `follow the token part`. Hope that would help. Let me know if you still have any concern.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, thanks for replying but it is not working.

Comment: Could you please share your problem or code snippet  so that it can be reproduce.

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, I have updated question and added code, it is giving me 400 status error.

Comment: Seems your `resource` is not correct. It should be `https://datalake.azure.net/ `

Comment: @MdFaridUddinKiron, let me try with this but I dont think it should be go generic, as I have to mention which datalake I want to connect to right?

Comment: Your clientId and secret would define where need to connect. I got token using that. Let me know asap.

Comment: still got 400 status code, A single clientId and secret can be assigned to multiple resources..

Comment: Resource should look like `resource:https://datalake.azure.net/`, I think you are doing something additional. [See here](https://imgur.com/J75Yxdu)

Comment: Additionally you refer to this [official document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/master/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake/samples/Sample02_Auth.cs#L114)

Comment: @BilalShafqat Is that you want to use Azure AD access token to access data lake gen2?

Comment: @JimXu Thanks for replying. Well let me explain everything. I have the service principals: ClientId, ClientSecrets. And these service principals have the access of the Data lake Store Gen-2 resource. Now what I want is to somehow programmatic (C#) use these service principals and generate SAS token that I can use further. My need of SAS token is because Snowflake Warehouse allows you to create stages using SAS token. So I need this SAS token, Please guide me.

Comment: @BilalShafqat    What do you mean `SAS token`? Azure AD access token or [Azure storage SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-sas-overview)?

Comment: @JimXu,By this I mean Azure Storage SAS token.

Comment: @BilalShafqat please check my update.

Comment: @JimXu, thanks for helping, but I want to generate SAS of Data lake Gen-2 using service principals not from key. In your latest code you are using account key to generate SAS.

Comment: There is no way to create SAS on ADLS Gen2 container level yet.. We can create managed policies but I dont know what is use of that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code can be used to create SAS token for datalake gen2 using service principles:

Here Password is **Client Secret** and Username is **ClientId**.

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $Password
$Credential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $UserName, $securePassword
Connect-AzAccount -Credential $Credential -ServicePrincipal -Tenant $Tenant -Subscription $SubscriptionName

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Creating an account level SAS Token.."
## Get the storage account
$storageAcc=Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Name $storageAccName
## Get the storage account context
$ctx=$storageAcc.Context
## Creates an account-level SAS token.
New-AzStorageAccountSASToken -Context $ctx -Service Blob,File,Table,Queue -ResourceType Service,Container,Object -Permission "racwdlup" -StartTime "2020-06-18" -ExpiryTime "2022-06-18"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Azure AD access token to access Azure data lake gen2, please refer to the following code

1. create a service principal and assign Azure RABC role for the sp.

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
# it will assign Storage Blob Data Contributor to the sp at subscription level
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "mysample" --role Storage Blob Data Contributor
```

[image]

2. Code

```
string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantId>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token";
var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

//I am Using client_credentials as It is mostly recommended
tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
                ["client_id"] = "--------",
                ["client_secret"] = "-------",
                ["resource"] = "https://storage.azure.com/"
            });

            dynamic json;
AccessTokenClass results = new AccessTokenClass();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

var tokenResponse = client.SendAsync(tokenRequest).GetAwaiter();

json = tokenResponse.GetResult().Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter();
results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);
```

---

If you want to create sas token, please refer to the following steps

1. get the account key via Azure Portal
   [image]
2. code

```
var key = account key you copy";
            var accountName = "testadls05";
            StorageSharedKeyCredential credential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, key);
            AccountSasBuilder sas = new AccountSasBuilder
            {
                Protocol = SasProtocol.None,
                Services = AccountSasServices.Blobs,
                ResourceTypes = AccountSasResourceTypes.All,
                StartsOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(-1),
                ExpiresOn = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddHours(1),

            };
            sas.SetPermissions(AccountSasPermissions.All);

            var uri = $"https://{accountName}.dfs.core.windows.net/";

            UriBuilder sasUri = new UriBuilder(uri);
            sasUri.Query = sas.ToSasQueryParameters(credential).ToString();

            DataLakeServiceClient service = new DataLakeServiceClient(sasUri.Uri);
            var result =service.GetFileSystems().First();
            Console.WriteLine(result.Name);
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for helping, but I want to generate SAS of Data lake Gen-2 using service principals not from key. In your latest code you are using account key to generate SAS.

Comment: @BilalShafqat We have no way to use service principals to create sas token : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/create-account-sas

Comment: @BilalShafqatb Do you have any other concerns?