# azure - user info - get more

Tags: azure, oauth, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have registered app in Azure. I `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users` to get userinfo.

Is there any option to get all info about user? And see what data can I get in JSON reponse?

Now when I use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users I get only couple information like:

```
{
    "aio": "kjaldjsfhkjsadhflkdhsafkjadhsfa",
    "amr": "[\"pwd\"]",
    "family_name": "Picasso",
    "given_name": "Pablo",
    "ipaddr": "11.12.113.144",
    "name": "Pablo Picasso",
    "oid": "234234-2343-4343-43434-2342342",
    "onprem_sid": "234234234-23-423-4-234-2-34-234",
    "sub": "234233q45rtferfwverfwgw45grfg45g45",
    "tid": "sdfkjgasdhjfgasjdhfgashjdfgasdhjf",
    "unique_name": "pablo.picasso@company.com",
    "upn": "pablo.picasso@company.com",
    "uti": "kajshdfkljahsdfkjahsdkjfahsd",
    "ver": "1.0"
}
```

Actually I'm looking for username. We can login to Windows using shortcut or email. So if user name is Pablo Picasso user can login with username PaPi. And I'm looking for that.

Comment: which information is missing?

Comment: we can login to Windows using shortcut or email. So if user name is Pablo Picasso user can login with username PaPi. And I'm looking for that.

Comment: Microsoft Graph provides [these user property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) So you only can get those.

Comment: OK, so how to get `employeeId` or `identities` or `officeLocation` into my JSON? :)

Comment: Please see the answer and feel free to share if you have any more concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Considering, you already know [how to get token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436419/get-group-members-from-azure-ad-via-microsoft-graph/60437235#60437235). Now see below example

If you want to fetch `employeeId` or `identities` or `officeLocation` using `Microsoft Graph API`. 
try following way:

***`Request:`***

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=employeeId ,identities ,officeLocation
```

***`Response:`***

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(employeeId,identities,officeLocation)",
    "@odata.nextLink": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=employeeId+%2cidentities+%2cofficeLocation&$skiptoken=X%27445370740",
    "value": [
        {
            "employeeId": 0200010000001C3A54696E614068616E,
            "officeLocation": Redmond, Usa,
            "identities": [
                {
                    "signInType": "userPrincipalName",
                    "issuer": "someEmail.onmicrosoft.com",
                    "issuerAssignedId": "tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

See the screen shot below:

[image]

Please refer to [Official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#select-parameter) if you need more details.

Comment: Is there any option to get all fields? :) and see all informations about user?
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me`  shows ony basic, to get `employeeId` I need to add it in `$select`. Can I get all fields?

Comment: No there is not such option. In that case you have to add your required property on $select part.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks [Md Farid Uddin Kiron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9663070/md-farid-uddin-kiron)

My workaround with all fields (without `mailboxSettings` because get error 403 access denied)

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me?$select=aboutMe,accountEnabled,ageGroup,assignedLicenses,assignedPlans,birthday,businessPhones,city,companyName,consentProvidedForMinor,country,createdDateTime,creationType,deletedDateTime,department,displayName,employeeId,faxNumber,givenName,hireDate,id,identities,imAddresses,mailNickname,mobilePhone,mySite,officeLocation,onPremisesDistinguishedName,onPremisesDomainName,onPremisesExtensionAttributes,onPremisesImmutableId,onPremisesLastSyncDateTime,onPremisesProvisioningErrors,onPremisesSamAccountName,onPremisesSecurityIdentifier,onPremisesSyncEnabled,onPremisesUserPrincipalName,otherMails,passwordPolicies,passwordProfile,pastProjects,postalCode,preferredDataLocation,preferredLanguage,preferredName,provisionedPlans,proxyAddresses,refreshTokensValidFromDateTime,responsibilities,schools,showInAddressList,skills,signInSessionsValidFromDateTime,state,streetAddress,surname,usageLocation,userPrincipalName,userType,interests,isResourceAccount,jobTitle,lastPasswordChangeDateTime,legalAgeGroupClassification,licenseAssignmentStates,mail
```