# Azure app oauth2 generating wrong access token in Client Credentials grant type

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I am a beginner in using Azure AD with OAuth2. I deployed a sample WEB API in my Azure AD. I consume my WEB API through the Postman application. Before consume the WEB API in Postman I need to generate the access token. But when i generate the access token in post man it's always accept the `Grant Type - Authentication Code`. When i change the value to `Client Credentials` the generated access token is not accepted in the API. it's shows `UnAuthorized` message.

In Azure portal - app settings  'Certificates & Secrets' window i create a client secret with description 'postman'. I didn't upload the certificate in this app.

I want to generate the access token with 'Grant Type' value 'Client Credentials'. Is there any additional configuration for this ?

Comment: Hi Ragesh could please share your code snippet to investigate quickly meanwhile you could have a look on how you could [generate token using client credentials grant flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436419/get-group-members-from-azure-ad-via-microsoft-graph/60437235#60437235)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`Is there any additional configuration for this ?`**

> No, there is no additional settings for generating token using
>   [`client_credentials`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow).

You all need following parameter:

1. `client_id`
2. `client_secret`
3. `resource` (`For v2.0` `scope`)
4. `grant_type`

**How Would You Request Token In PostMan :**

**`Your Token Endpoint:`**

***`https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenent.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token`***
`Method Type:` `POST`

**`Request Body:`**

`grant_type:client_credentials`

`client_id:00ab01_Your_Azure-Ad_Application_Id_fbbf8e`

`client_secret:XNk2zgXx_Your_Azure-Ad_Application_Secret_vjdz2Q`

`resource:https://graph.microsoft.com/`

See the screenshot:

[image]

**Code Snippet:**

```cs
  //Token Request End Point
    string tokenUrl = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/YourTenant.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/token";
    var tokenRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, tokenUrl);

    //I am Using client_credentials as It is mostly recommended
    tokenRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["grant_type"] = "client_credentials",
        ["client_id"] = "b6695c7be_YourClient_Id_e6921e61f659",
        ["client_secret"] = "Vxf1SluKbgu4PF0Nf_Your_Secret_Yp8ns4sc=",
        ["resource"] = "https://graph.microsoft.com/" 
    });

    dynamic json;
    AccessTokenClass results = new AccessTokenClass();
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var tokenResponse = await client.SendAsync(tokenRequest);

    json = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AccessTokenClass>(json);
```

**Class Used:**

```cs
public class AccessTokenClass
   {
        public string token_type { get; set; }
        public string expires_in { get; set; }
        public string resource { get; set; }
        public string access_token { get; set; }
   }
```

Hope that would help. If you still have any concern feel free to share.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable answer. This is really helpfull for me. Now I can generate the access token with 'Client Credentials' grant type. But when i add this access token into my request header it shows 401 Unauthorized error.

Comment: Oh I see, which API you are trying to access with the token? please add your code snippet to investigate it faster. Usually 401 happens when your token doesn't has permission API you are trying to access. So you have to set permission on your token to access the URL you trying to access. Hope you got my point

Comment: I really sorry for the late response, Now I am not in the office now because I am in Cochin Kerala, In our city it's really pathetic situation because of the COVID 19. I will response as soon as possible.