# Azure AD Access Token Request

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, webassembly, blazor-client-side

In my WebAssembly Blazor App, I need to access an API that I'm developing and Microsoft.Graph.

As I understood, I cannot use the same bearer token for 2 different resources (my API and Graph).

I setup the access to my API with MSAL in Program.cs

```cs
builder.Services.AddBaseAddressHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
{
    var authentication = options.ProviderOptions.Authentication;
    authentication.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx";
    authentication.ClientId = "xxx";
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("xxx/user_impersonation");
});
```

And I'm trying to get the token for the Graph API directly when I need it (following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0)):

```cs
internal class Token
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public int ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("refresh_token")]
    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }
}

private static async Task<Token> GetElibilityToken(HttpClient client)
{
    string baseAddress = @"https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token";

    string grant_type = "authorization_code";
    string client_id = "xxx";
    string client_secret = "==xxx";
    string scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default";

    var form = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {"grant_type", grant_type},
            {"client_id", client_id},
            {"client_secret", client_secret},
            {"scope", scope }
        };

    HttpResponseMessage tokenResponse = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress, new FormUrlEncodedContent(form));
    var jsonContent = await tokenResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Token tok = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(jsonContent);
    return tok;
}
```

Is the approach correct? Is there a better one?

Should I register 2 `IAccessTokenProvider` in Program.cs? How?

The problem I have is that I keep getting the error:

```
Access to fetch at 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token' from origin 'https://localhost:xxx' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
dotnet.3.2.0-preview2.20159.2.js:1 POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxx/oauth2/v2.0/token net::ERR_FAILED
```

How do I setup CORS in my request?

Comment: You can try [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60771696/azure-app-oauth2-generating-wrong-access-token-in-client-credentials-grant-type/60773200#60773200)

Comment: Did you ever fix the CORS issue? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: Yes, as in the answer, every time I make a request I specify the single scope I need. After I did that it worked correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the options to specify the scopes, each time you request a new token:

```
IAccessTokenProvider authService; /* inject your IAccessTokenProvider */

var tokenResult = await authService .RequestAccessToken(
    new AccessTokenRequestOptions
    {
        ReturnUrl = "...",
        Scopes = new string[] { "..." }
    });
```